# moshi serialization support like @jsonunwrapped

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, moshi

I have a POJO like this:

```
class Registration {
    String name;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    ModifiableDetails detailsToModify;
}

class ModifiableDetails {
    String currentStatus;
    int enrollmentNumber;
}
```

When I'm making a rest request with content

```
{ "name":"Lucy", "currentStatus":"active","enrollmentNumber":001}
```

Spring RestController is deserializing it as Registration POJO as it uses Jackson for deserialization.
After that, when I'm again serializing the object with Moshi adapter, I'm getting a json like this:

```
{
 "name":"Lucy", 
 "detailsToModify":{
     "currentStatus":"active",
     "enrollmentNumber":001
  }
}
```

Is it possible with Moshi to serialize the object like:

```
{ "name":"Lucy", "currentStatus":"active","enrollmentNumber":001}
```

Or is there any other JsonAdapter(except Jackson) available to serialize the object that way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is with a one-off JsonAdapter using an intermediate type.

```
final class RegistrationJson {
  static final Object ADAPTER = new Object() {
    @FromJson Registration fromJson(RegistrationJson json) {
      return new Registration(json.name,
          new ModifiableDetails(json.currentStatus, json.enrollmentNumber));
    }

    @ToJson RegistrationJson toJson(Registration registration) {
      return new RegistrationJson(registration.name, registration.detailsToModify.currentStatus,
          registration.detailsToModify.enrollmentNumber);
    }
  };

  final String name;
  final String currentStatus;
  final int enrollmentNumber;

  RegistrationJson(String name, String currentStatus, int enrollmentNumber) {
    this.name = name;
    this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
    this.enrollmentNumber = enrollmentNumber;
  }
}
```

Register it with your Moshi instance, and you can run the following.

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(RegistrationJson.ADAPTER).build();
JsonAdapter<Registration> adapter = moshi.adapter(Registration.class);
Registration registration = adapter.fromJson("{ \"name\":\"Lucy\", \"currentStatus\":\"active\",\"enrollmentNumber\":1}");
String json = adapter.toJson(registration);
```

Note that 001 is not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks @Eric. Definitely, that's a way of doing it. But i wanted it to be generic so that i can serialize it just by using .class (e.g. by passing Registration.class here)

Comment: By passing Registration.class where?